# Finding large files

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, file-system

Just looking for some feedback. I designed a script to find big files that are taking up lots of space. Still a beginner, and appreciative of constructive feedback, with both the function and form/style/formatting.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# findlargefiles.py Searches a file location and subdirectories for
# files larger than a given size.
"""
findlargefiles.py Searches a file location and subdirectories for
files larger than a given size.

Created on Sun Sep  3 20:35:12 2017

@author: toonarmycaptain
"""

import os


def searchfolder(location, filesize):
    FileNotFoundErrorsCount = 0
    filesfoundcount = 0
    print('Files larger than '+str(int(filesize))+' MB in location: '+location)
    for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(location):
            for filename in filenames:
                try:
                    actualsize = os.path.getsize(os.path.join(foldername,
                                                              filename))
                    if filesize*1024**2 <= actualsize:
                        print(foldername
                              + '\\'  # file path + \ + file name
                              + filename
                              + ' - '
                              + '{:.2f} MB'.format(actualsize/1024**2))
                        filesfoundcount += 1
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    FileNotFoundErrorsCount += 1
                    print('FileNotFoundError: '+filename)
    print('Files found: '+str(filesfoundcount))
    if FileNotFoundErrorsCount > 0:
        print('FileNotFoundErrors: '+str(FileNotFoundErrorsCount))


print('This program searches for files larger than a given size '
      'in a given location.')

while True:
    location = input("Where would you like to search? ")
    if os.path.exists(location):
        break
    else:
        print('Please enter a valid path.')
filesize = float(input('Please enter file size in MB: '))

searchfolder(location, filesize)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more flexible approach would separate the printing from the finding. This allows you to use `search_folder` for other purposes, and cleans up the logic a bit.

More idiomatically in Python this might be formatted something like:

```
def search_folder(location, min_filesize):
    for folder, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(location):
        for filename in filenames:
            try:
                size_bytes = os.path.getsize(os.path.join(foldername, filename))
                if min_filesize * 1024 ** 2 <= size_bytes:
                    yield filename, size_bytes
            except FileNotFoundError:
                # maybe log error, maybe `pass`, maybe raise an exception
                # (halting further processing), maybe return an error object

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('This program searches for ...')
    ...

    print('Files larger than %d MB in location: %s' % (filesize, location))
    for filename, size in search_folder(location, filesize):
        print(...)
```

- The `if __name__ == '__main__'` block allows you to import this script in other Python files, without triggering the interactive logic.
- `search_folder` now returns an iterator of `(filename, size)` pairs, and leaves the printing up to the function that calls it.

  - Now I can run this with no printing, purely to count files, for example.
- Standard Python style is to use `underscore_case` for function and variable names, and especially to start with lowercase (eg. `files_not_found_count` instead of `FileNotFoundErrorsCount`)
- Wrapping things in `str()` when printing is unnecessary if you use one of the various string-formatting tools (`%`-formatting or `'{}'.format`) instead of `+`
- I'm not sure under what conditions you would get `FileNotFoundError` on paths returned from `os.walk`, other than deleted files. If that's true in general, the most appropriate error handling may just be to silently continue.

Comment: Thankyou so much - I hadn't learned about importing code I'd written yet, but I tried importing it and it worked! (Pretty exciting for me).

Comment: I had already used `.format()` once, I don't know why I didn't do it for the rest. Fixed now.

Comment: The error was originally happening because I wasn't getting the file paths right for subfolders, and at the time I thought it was for hidden files or something(like it could see names, but not sizes), because the script returns a bunch of files I don't see in .File Explorer.

Comment: Am I right in following that what you're doing to avoid the print statement is to use the yield statement, and duplicating what was originally there, with the print statements inside `if __name__ == '__main__':`?

Comment: @toonarmycaptain Yup. I just moved your input loop and all the print statements into the `if __name__` block, and gave it its own loop (`for filename, size in search_folder(..)`) that will receive the `filename, size` pairs that `search_folder` has found to be over the min size.